# How set up a 2-way email anonymizer in nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I have a NodeJS application. I know I can use nodemailer or haraka to send transactional emails programmatically. But where would I start if I want to create a 2-way email relay in order to hide email recipient addresses from each other? Similar to what Craigslist does when one responds to their listing. Basically, I want users to reply to my randomly generated emails at the same domain, but have their email correspondence deliverered to their actual emails. Do I need to set up my own mail server or can I use something like Amazon SES?

Answer (score 3):

I've built this before:
Use Mailgun to set up MX records on a subdomain and also set up a "route" to hit an endpoint on your application when a mail is received - it's like a webhook.
Use an instance identifier for the "connection" that lives in your system (not a DB pkey field, but similar). So your mail format would be similar to [instance UUID]@sub.domain.com. This is the address email is always sent to and Mailgun catches it and parses it through the route rules.
Use regex in your Mailgun route to identify and capture the account in the email address (the instance ID) and add it to the webhook API request. Add the `sender` value to the request and your application should be able to tell which instance the email is in reference to and who sent it, which lets you identify the recipient easily (the other party in your instance).
Then use Mailgun to relay the email to the other party, using your instance email address as the `from`.
That's really the basics in a nutshell. Mailgun's route feature really makes this easy. You only need the Mailgun SDK which you can get as a lib on npm.